# Is there a better way to replace multiple spaces in file names?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've searched around S.O and google but haven't found a solution that I understood straight away.
The code below is what I have.

(I have added comments below just for clarity on s.o)
I would like it to have a shorter signature but remain very understandable/readable

The Code:

```
def fix_filenames_in(folder):
    ''' Removes spaces from filenames within a folder '''
    files = os.listdir(folder)

    for file_name in files:
        new_name = ''
        if ' ' in file_name:

            # I could have used .replace() but decided to go with splitting on the space
            new_name = file_name.split(" ")

            # This filters empty splits in the list: ['file', '', 'name'] -> ['file', 'name']
            # Is there a better way to do this?
            new_name = [segment for segment in new_name if not segment == '']
            new_name = '-'.join(new_name)

            # Building file paths
            old_filename = folder + os.sep + file_name
            new_filename = folder + os.sep + new_name

            # Actual renaming
            os.rename(old_filename, new_filename)
```

Running it:

```
# Assuming the following list is from the os.listdir() call
images = ['bat  man.jpg', 'cat woman.jpg', 'the  scary  joker.png']

fix_filenames_in(images)

# Result:
['bat-man.jpg', 'cat-woman.jpg', 'the-scary-joker.png']
```

Comment: Regex: `re.sub('\\s+', '-', file_name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.split` to tokenize based on (possibly multiple) whitespace, then `str.join` with a `'-'` character to join back into a single string again.

```
def fix_filenames_in(images):
    return ['-'.join(i.split()) for i in images]

>>> fix_filenames_in(images)
['bat-man.jpg', 'cat-woman.jpg', 'the-scary-joker.png']
```

A regex solution would be to use `re.sub` with the pattern `r'\s+'` to match one or more whitespace characters.

```
import re

def fix_filenames_in(images):
    return [re.sub(r'\s+', '-', i) for i in images]

>>> fix_filenames_in(images)
['bat-man.jpg', 'cat-woman.jpg', 'the-scary-joker.png']
```

Comment: Thank you @Cory Kramer. The function doesn't actually return anything, It just renames files. But I like this approach very much.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `replace()`?

This might work for you:

```
file_name = file_name.replace(' ', '-')
```

EDIT: I didn't consider the case where there are multiple spaces. In that case, you want to replace an arbitrary number of sequential spaces with a singular '-'. Consider:

```
import re

file_name = re.sub('\s+', '-', file_name)
```

The `\s` says look for spaces and the `+` says to look for at least one.

Comment: Thank you and yes I have. The problem I had with .replace() was if the filename had 2 space chars I would end up with 2 dashes -- instead of a single dash

Comment: @BernardSolien have you tried anything with regexes? If you're looking for something simple, replace with regex would solve this issue. Edited my answer to address multiple spaces.

Comment: Thanks, @Jace. I think I have a partial solution from Cory Kramer below. I'll tinker with it a little to do what I want.